# php: WHILE continuous display of data

Tags: php, html, mysql

Okay I have a table called **users** and in that table contains:

```
Students Name:     Grade:
1. Ben             1
2. Cathy           1
3. Tom             1
4. Mark            1
5. Lisa            1
6. Bernard         1
7. John            2
8. Macy            2
9. Rose            2
10. Maynard        2
11. Bill           2
12. Sherlock       2
```

So basically, I have **6 Grade 1 Students** and **6 Grade 2 Students.** I want to display them based on their grades using a two-columned Table:

```
----------------------------------
Grade 1 
----------------------------------
Table 1          |    Table 2
                 |
                 |
```

The purpose of this is I want to save space by not displaying all the Grades 1 in a single column, I want that *table 1* and *table 2* will each display 3 Grades 1 based on the records.

I tried using this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE grade = '$grade1' LIMIT 3";
$result = mysqli_query($connectdb,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $name = $row['name'];
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>";
   echo $name;
   echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

}
```

I placed this on the **Table 1** and **Table 2**. It worked. However both tables displayed the same names:

```
----------------------------------
Grade 1 
----------------------------------
Table 1          |Table 2
   Ben           |  Ben
   Cathy         |  Cathy
   Tom           |  Tom
```

How can I make it using like this:

```
----------------------------------
Grade 1 
----------------------------------
Table 1          |Table 2
   Ben           |  Mark
   Cathy         |  Lisa
   Tom           |  Bernard
```

Forgive my lack of knowledge, I'm actually new to WHILE commands.

Comment: If you execute the same query twice, then why do you expect different results?

Comment: Change the value of `$grade1` from 1 to 2 when you execute the query the second time

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: To do it in two columns you'll have to fetch the two result sets and then fold them together into another array by collating them.

Comment: @tadman, Wow! Thanks! I didn't know that it's dangerous to directly link the data to query like that. Thank you so much!

Comment: @tadman Sir/ma'am, what do you mean when you said "fetch the two results sets and then fold them together into another array by collating them" ? I don't quite get it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you are retrieving only 1st 3 students data and displaying it twice..

There are two ways 1st way

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE grade = '$grade1'";

$result = mysqli_query($connectdb,$sql);

$i=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 if($i==0 || $i==3){
   echo "<table>"
 }
   $name = $row['name'];
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>";
   echo $name;
   echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 if($i==0 || $i==3){
    echo "</table>"
 }
$i++;
}
```

second way add one more, here you are retrieving the remaining 3 students data and need to display it in different table

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE grade = '$grade1' LIMIT 3,3";

$result = mysqli_query($connectdb,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $name = $row['name'];
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>";
   echo $name;
   echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

}
```

Comment: Thanks I think this is the one that I like, I just don't get the 'LIMIT 3, 3' why is there a second '3' and that, how can I use this to the 2nd table to display 4-6 instead of 1-3?

Comment: Second 3 three tells how many records you want, first tells starting from.

Comment: So if I want to display from 4-6, I'll just write `LIMIT 4,3` right?

Comment: No it is limit 3,3 because row index in table starts from 0, so your code limit 4,3 means from 5 to 7